# Jenkins file: Trigger another project with parameters returning "null"

Tags: spring, maven, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm trying to make a front-end project on jenkins to trigger my QA project, only using the jenkinsfile.

Atm the frontend project has a stage that will trigger my job with the following code:

```html
    stage('Trigger QA job'){
          build '../qa-project/qatests'
          //parameters: [[$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: 'environment', value: "$environment"]]
          parameters: [string(name: 'environment', value: $env.environment)]
          wait: true
```

and the `environment` is declared right at the beggining of the pipeline like so:

```
node('PCF') {
    def environment = 'test'

...
```

On the Qa project i'm running the test with this method on the jenkinsfile:

```html
    stage('tests'){
      runTests()
    }

def runTests(Map params = [:]){
  def targetFolder = $env.targetfolder ?: "tests"
  sh "chmod u+x mvnw"

    configFileProvider([configFile(fileId: jenkinsSettingsXmlId, variable: 'MAVEN_SETTINGS)]){
      def targetEnv = sh "echo $env.environment"
      sh "SPRING_PROFILE_ACTIVE=$targetEnvironment ./mvnw -B -s $MAVEN_SETTINGS -Dtest.folder=$targetFolder test
```

Returning this error:

````
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] sh
+ echo null
null

...

groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: environment for class: groovy.lang.Binding
    at groovy.lang.Binding.getVariable(Binding.java:63)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onGetProperty(SandboxInterceptor.java:270)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$6.call(Checker.java:291)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedGetProperty(Checker.java:295)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedGetProperty(Checker.java:271)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.SandboxInvoker.getProperty(SandboxInvoker.java:29)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.PropertyAccessBlock.rawGet(PropertyAccessBlock.java:20)
    at WorkflowScript.run(WorkflowScript:41)
    at ___cps.transform___(Native Method)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.PropertyishBlock$ContinuationImpl.get(PropertyishBlock.java:74)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.LValueBlock$GetAdapter.receive(LValueBlock.java:30)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.PropertyishBlock$ContinuationImpl.fixName(PropertyishBlock.java:66)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor305.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationPtr$ContinuationImpl.receive(ContinuationPtr.java:72)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ConstantBlock.eval(ConstantBlock.java:21)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Next.step(Next.java:83)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable$1.call(Continuable.java:174)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable$1.call(Continuable.java:163)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport$ThreadCategoryInfo.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:129)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:268)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable.run0(Continuable.java:163)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.access$001(SandboxContinuable.java:18)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.run0(SandboxContinuable.java:51)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThread.runNextChunk(CpsThread.java:185)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.run(CpsThreadGroup.java:405)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.access$400(CpsThreadGroup.java:96)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:317)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:281)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsVmExecutorService$2.call(CpsVmExecutorService.java:67)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at hudson.remoting.SingleLaneExecutorService$1.run(SingleLaneExecutorService.java:131)
    at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$1.run(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:28)
    at jenkins.security.ImpersonatingExecutorService$1.run(ImpersonatingExecutorService.java:59)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)```


i've managed to make it before catch a "null" variable not letting me advance too, trying other approaches. I would like to know if is there a way to make this run without any plugin type of approach, as i wanted it to be the most abstract as possible.

Thanks in advance.
````

Comment: The error implies your `environment` key in the `env` map is `null`. We would need to see where this value is assigned.

Comment: hi @MattSchuchard i've edited with the info where the environment is declared. It's being declared right at the beggining of the front-end pipeline.

Comment: So that would be a Jenkins Pipeline variable and not an environment variable. Try accessing it directly via `environment` instead of within the `env` map where the environment variables are stored.

Comment: changed and still getting the error: ```groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: environment for class: groovy.lang.Binding```

Comment: Changes made on the jenkinsfile, but still returning null on the downstream job (qa project)

Answer (score 0):

As you have declared a parameter in your downstream build like

```
parameters {
        string(name: "environment", defaultValue: "", description: "The environment")
    }
```

You need to access the value of the parameter using params:

```
echo "Environment is ${params.environment}"
```

Also see documentation: https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#parameters